# How to inherit DialogFragment

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

First question asked so comment if you need more details.

I'm been working with Xamarin for some months now, and I have this problem that I can't inherit `DialogFragment`. I've watching some videos with Joe Rock, but now i'm stuck with this problem.

I have the using Android.App;
and the necessary references.

It's just a new empty class. Another thing is, that the intellisense is not responsive either when I'm typing

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace LoginSystem
{
    public class dialog_SignUp : DialogFragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found my "workaround" by deleting my 'icon.png' file from Resources/Drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `OnCreateDialog` and specify what actually you wanna do with your new custom list.

Possible solution might look like this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using SupportDialogFragment = Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment;

namespace Example.Android.App.Views.Base
{
    public class ListDialogFragment : SupportDialogFragment
    {
        public static readonly string TAG = "LIST_DIALOG";

        string _title;
        IList<string> _items;

        public static ListDialogFragment NewInstance(IList<string> items, string title)
        {
            ListDialogFragment frag = new ListDialogFragment();
            frag._items = items;
            frag._title = title;
            return frag;
        }

        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
            builder.SetTitle(_title)
                   .SetItems(_items.ToArray(), (sender, e) => { /* implement your item click listener here */ })
                   .SetCancelable(true)
                   .SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (sender, e) => { /* implement your Cancel button click listener here */ });

            return builder.Create();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget then to call it properly from your activity

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
// Add list items

ListDialogFragment frag = ListDialogFragment.NewInstance(items, "List title");
frag.Show(SupportFragmentManager, ListDialogFragment.TAG);
```

https://gist.github.com/olegflo/0fae549dd31ab1e21a36fcd73e8967de